# execute php code by pressing a button inside form before submitting the form itself

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have a form with several fields. One of those fields is an input file field where user can upload a JSON file. 
**My need:** When a button is pressed (not to submit form) I need to grab that input file field and pass it to a function executing it, but without submitting the form itself.

```
<form action=''>
    <input type="text" name="abc">
    <input type="text" name="cde">
    <input type='file' name='import' />
        <button class="button" type='submit' name='restore'>
            <span class="icon-upload"> </span> Restore
        </button>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

How can I achieve it?

Comment: You should post in question your failing attempt, if any...

Comment: ajax is probably what you need if it has to be a php function, could it not be done with a javascript function?

Comment: I'm stumbling over your description "upload a json file and execute it". what exactly is this json data and what should be executed?

Comment: @cari Sorry for not to be clear enough. I don´t want to execute the file itself, I only need to pass it to the function. My problem is how to pass it without submitting the form

Comment: pass it to a js function or a php function?

Comment: @cari to a php function

Comment: @Billy it has to be a php function

Comment: You want to pass the file location ? or the content of the file ?

Comment: @Dwza Need the content file

Comment: The fact that you want the file content you need to upload it first. But you dont want to submit the form so you need a ajax upload and than return the content after uploading it. May someone provides you with some source but I guess its better for you to search in google for all components.

Answer (score 0):

you need to capture the button click with javascript, preferably jquery, and post it via ajax to a php-script. look up "ajax" on jquery.

include jquery in your file
then change the input and button to somthing like that:

```
<input type='file' id="myinput" name='import' />
<button class="button" id="ajaxsubmit">restore</button>
```

after this, add the ajax call (read the sample code from api.jquery.com):

```
$("#ajaxsubmit").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);
  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "receiver.php",
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false    
  });
});
```

finally set up your php-file receiver.php where you work with your received file data like you would when the form gets submitted.

http://jsfiddle.net/9nfn2Las/

Comment: why you calling ajax if he actually only want to have the input of the fied ?? Is just a string that has to be passed and not the file its self. By the way, this would also submit the form since `button` has no type `button` (type="button")

Comment: oh ok, i see.. you need a file upload function, i will edit my answer

Comment: so he made it clear in the comments now... he needs the content of the file so ajax is neede.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
var form = document.forms.formName("fileinput"); \\ change the form name and the file input
form.addEventListener('submit', function(ev) {

var
oOutput = document.getElementById("output"),
oData = new FormData(document.forms.formNAme("fileinput"));

oData.append("CustomField", "This is some extra data");\\if you need to...

var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("POST", "thepphpfile.php", true);
oReq.onload = function(oEvent) {
if (oReq.status == 200) {
  oOutput.innerHTML = "Sent!";
} else {
  oOutput.innerHTML = "Error " + oReq.status + " occurred uploading your file.<br \/>";
}
};

oReq.send(oData);
ev.preventDefault();
}, false);
```